# Baofeng UV5RA Unable to Program anything in 400-480 Bands

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r, radio-programming

I'm running Chirp on Linux Mint 17.2 and for some reason when I try to program anything in 400mhz-480mhz range I get the error.
"Error setting memory: Frequency 453.66250 is out of supported range" 
When I download from the Radio it has channels like 456.525000 so is there any reason I shouldn't be able to program something like 453.66250 or 460.25000

In order to Download and Upload to the Radio I do have to run chirp as root.
Could this be the problem?

I also have this issue when trying to program the channel manually.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working with someone from chirp who took an image file from my radio and modified it to work. He said that my radio had been setup with an image for the 220 model radio. This was the second radio he'd done this for in 10 days. I'm not sure how someone would go about making the changes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this issue was solved on [the Chirp issues forum](http://chirp.danplanet.com/issues/2859), however without instructions. I might recommend posting what you did here, as the Baofeng family of radios has quirks that cause this.

Also, just to offer insight, running something as root in Linux is akin to running programs as administrator in Windows. Root is the superuser, and should be the ONLY one on your system with permissions to make changes to it. Otherwise any user profile would be able to mess about willy nilly, which has obvious security concerns.